# Import csv, export queries, delete queries then repeat

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have researched the code for this online for weeks but still cannot find what I need so any help will be greatly appreciated:

I need to:

1) Import the first CSV in "C:\Documents" and create a table called "Data" with import specs I have already created.

2) Create and export all fields in a (SELECT?) query (Sport = Football, Event = Match Odds) to an excel binary file called "Match Odds 001"
I then wish to delete the data contained in this query from the Table "Data".

3) Repeat step 2) two hundred times with different Events exporting each query to an excel binary file with the name "(Event) 001" then deleting that query data from the table.

4) After all queries have run and been deleted, any remaining data in the table will be exported to an excel binary file named "Misc 001" and then this data deleted from the Table "Data" (or maybe even delete the Table "Data" completely.)

5) Repeat from 1) importing the 2nd CSV file from "C:\Documents" and exporting queries to Excel Binary files named "(Event) 002" so as not to replace the previous files.

This would continue until all CSVs have been imported and split.

As there are 200 queries I'd prefer to create them in VBA code.

I have just started using VBA in Access and so far have found code which will import all csv files in a folder so I am hoping to insert code to create, export then delete the queries.

Any help on the vba coding required is hugely appreciated.

.

.

UPDATE: With massive thanks to Mike I now have the following code but a few small issues have surfaced.

1) How can I compact the Database to reduce the filesize after the "DoCmd.RunSQL "DROP TABLE Data"" command?
I wish to repeatedly import 500MB CSV's then delete them so after I import and drop the first then import the second the filesize becomes 1GB and is increasing.

2) How difficult is it to include a second column in the Events Table so that my SELECT query becomes WHERE Event=Event & Selection=Selection and to combine both these fields to create the filename?

3) The Events Table used to create the Queries and file names sometimes contains characters that cannot be used in file names, for Example "/" & "?". Can these be easily dropped to create the filenames or might it be better to add a further column to the Events Table which would contain the filename to be used (ie a combination of Event and Selection but with the disallowed characters removed)

If I can solve these issues I will have the perfect code for my needs, again with all credit to Mike.

```
    Sub ImportAndSplit()

    Dim fileCounter As String
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sql As String
    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Dim file As String
    Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\Robbie\Documents\Data\" 'Directory Path
    Dim strFile As String 'Filename
    Dim strFileList() As String 'File  Array
    Dim intFile As Integer 'File Number

strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv") 'Loop through the folder & build file list

While strFile <> ""
    intFile = intFile + 1 'add files to the list
    ReDim Preserve strFileList(1 To intFile)
    strFileList(intFile) = strFile
    strFile = Dir()
Wend

If intFile = 0 Then 'see if any files were found
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
End If

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Export")

sql = "SELECT Event FROM Events"

rs.Open sql, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList) 'cycle through the list of files & import to Access creating a new table called Data
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Data", "Data", strPath & strFileList(intFile)

fileCounter = Format(intFile, "000") 'format i so that when you use it in file names, the files sort intuitively

Do While Not rs.EOF

sql = "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Event='" & rs!Event & "'" 'select the records to export and export them
file = "C:\Users\Robbie\Documents\Data Split\" & rs!Event & " " & fileCounter & ".xlsb" 'use the counter to distinguish between which csv your exporting from
qdf.sql = sql
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, qdf.Name, file

sql = "DELETE FROM Data WHERE Event='" & rs!Event & "'" 'delete the records from the source table
DoCmd.RunSQL sql

rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.MoveFirst

'export remaining data
file = "C:\Users\Robbie\Documents\Data Split\Misc " & fileCounter & ".xlsb" 'use the counter to distinguish between which csv your exporting from
sql = "SELECT * FROM Data"
qdf.sql = sql
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, qdf.Name, file

'delete remaining data
'DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM Data"
'or delete the table
DoCmd.RunSQL "DROP TABLE Data"

Next

MsgBox UBound(strFileList) & " Files were Imported and Split"

rs.Close

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a table with your Events in it (in my example it's called "Events" and has one field "Event").
2. Create a query called "Export".  Doesn't matter what it does, we're going to overwrite it 200 times anyway.
3. Add the ActiveX Data Objects Library reference
4. Code:

   ```
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim fileCounter As String
   Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
   Dim sql As String
   Dim qdf As QueryDef
   Dim file As String


       DoCmd.SetWarnings False

       Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Export")

       sql = "SELECT Event FROM Events"

       rs.Open sql, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

       For i = 1 To x 'where x is however many csvs you're importing

           fileCounter = Format(i, "000") 'format i so that when you use it in file names, the files sort intuitively

           'run your import code here


           Do While Not rs.EOF

               'select the records to export and export them
               sql = "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Event='" & rs!Event & "'"
               file = "C:\Documents\" & rs!Event & fileCounter & ".xlsb" 'use the counter to distinguish between which csv your exporting from
               qdf.sql = sql
               DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, qdf.Name, file

               'delete the records from the source table
               sql = "DELETE FROM Data WHERE Event='" & rs!Event & "'"
               DoCmd.RunSQL sql

               rs.MoveNext
           Loop

           rs.MoveFirst

           'export remaining data
           file = "C:\Documents\MISC" & fileCounter & ".xlsb" 'use the counter to distinguish between which csv your exporting from
           sql = "SELECT * FROM Data"
           qdf.sql = sql
           DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, qdf.Name, file

           'delete remaining data
           DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM Data"
           'or delete the table
           'DoCmd.RunSQL "DROP TABLE Data"

       Next i

       rs.Close

       DoCmd.SetWarnings True
   ```

Make sure none of those files exist before running this, it will not overwrite files.  Either delete them manually or you could use the Windows Script Host in the loop to delete the files if they exist before creating them...

```
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

    If fso.FileExists(file) Then
        fso.DeleteFile (file)
    End If
```

In response to your updates:

1. Consider linking them instead of importing (`DoCmd.TransferText acLink, "Data"...`).  I don't believe it's possible to compact while you're working in a db, it would have to close.
2. You basically answered your own question.  If you want to do that, add the column to the table and update the SQL exactly how you said.
3. You could use the [Replace function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) but you'd have to run it for each illegal character and you might end up missing one.  It's probably best to do what you suggested and just create them yourself in a new column.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. I hadn't thought about automating the query creation and was resigned to writing out all 200 queries individually. I'll implement this solution ASAP. Thanks again.

Comment: I have adapted the code and it works well but 2 issues have surfaced and I have a further query. Thanks for all your help and if you can be of any further help thanks again. I have updated the question to reflect the current situation.

Comment: I've added some comments to my answer to address your updates.